# Difference between Office Graph APIs and Query Office Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Hi what is the difference between calling office graph API (like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) and making a query (like https:///_api/search/query?Querytext='Username:carls'&SourceId='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&SelectProperties='UserName,DocId')

Both of them need to be authenticated before running them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Francisco,
Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com) exposes a unified endpoint for Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services. In the case of the user profile information, the Microsoft Graph unified endpoint includes information coming from Azure AD, Exchange and SharePoint user profile. So when you call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName,aboutMe,photo the Microsoft Graph federates the call to each service (AAD, SharePoint and Exchange) to get each property and aggregates a single response for you. 
When you call the SharePoint search endpoint to get user profile information, first you need to discover the SharePoint endpoint for the customer, then you only get information stored in SharePoint. 
Yes, both of them have to be authenticated requests.

Answer (score 0):

The naming is quite confusing here:

- [**Microsoft Graph**](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) is an API unifying access to APIs for specific products, integrating authentication and aggregating information.
- **Office Graph** is completely different, providing insights into content and activity for Office365 users.

This [architecture diagram for Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/GraphDocuments/en-us/overview/images/MicrosoftGraph_DevStack.png) from the above page shows a block at the bottom for Office Graph, which is mostly unrelated - it provides insights about people, content and interactions based on Office365 usage.  This used to be known as [Delve / Project Oslo](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/11/introducing-codename-oslo-and-the-office-graph/) based on an acquisition.